# `gets.chomp.downcase!` gets a null string error

Tags: ruby, string

If I do

```
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!
```

I can input a string without an error
However, if I do

```
user_input = gets.chomp.downcase!
```

My `user_input` string is not populated and any subsequent work on the string returns error saying that my string is null. Why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String#downcase!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-downcase-21) returns `nil` if no changes were made.

```
'hello'.downcase!
# => nil
'hello'.downcase
# => "hello"
```

So if the string inputted has no uppercase letters, `gets.chomp.downcase!` returns `nil`.

Comment: Oh wow, that is neat. Also, thank you for editing my question